# How can we lead a life without attachments?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, teaching

In Bhagavad gita it was said that attachment is the main reason for our sorrows and it seems more difficult for me to follow because life seems nothing without attachments. So my question is what is really meant by that teaching and how's it possible to lead a life without attachments?

Comment: This seems like a opinion based question? Anyhow, attachments to life means in general = attachments to our thought process basically. Whatever thought arises gets converted to action. Detachment means, detaching yourself from bodily/thought process conception of life. When you detach from this, automatically you become a witness, and experience life as it is. When you experience something as it is = that's your true state.!

Comment: In Sankhya Yoga, it is explained that it is the nature of Gunas which is forcing you to do action and your real nature is therefore being a witness. So detaching from this false thought is of leading a life without attachments.